# Azure synapse With Databricks Framework for modern data warehouse

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am working On Databricks. I have curated data in form of fact and dims. Theses data  consume for power bi reporting by synapse. I am not sure what is the use of synapse, If data is already cook in databricks layer. why we are using synapse in this framework.

Answer (score 0):

> why we are using synapse in this framework

- An analytics service for data warehouses and large data is called Azure Synapse. We can combine Azure services like Power BI, Machine Learning, and others using Azure Synapse.
- It offers a number of connectors that make it easier to transfer a sizable volume of data between Azure Databricks and Azure Synapse. It also offers a mechanism for Azure Databricks users to connect to Azure Synapse.
- Additionally, Azure Synapse offers SQL pools for the computing environment and data warehousing.